# Error while running Qiskit code on real quantum hardware

Tags: qiskit, programming, ibm-q-experience

I started to learn Qiskit, so sorry if my question is very basic.  So far I used `qasm_simulator` or `state_vectorsimulator`, however, now I would like to run my circuit on real IBM Q processor.

Here is my code, I wanted to execute:

```
%matplotlib inline
# Importing standard Qiskit libraries and configuring account
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, QuantumRegister, ClassicalRegister, execute, Aer, IBMQ
from qiskit.compiler import transpile, assemble
from qiskit.tools.jupyter import *
from qiskit.visualization import *

provider = IBMQ.load_account()
backend = provider.backends(name='ibmq_ourense')

q = QuantumRegister(5, name = 'q')
c = ClassicalRegister(2,name = 'c')

circuit = QuantumCircuit(q,c)
circuit.h(q[0])
circuit.cx(q[0],q[1])
circuit.measure(q[0],c[0])
circuit.measure(q[1],c[1])

job = execute(circuit, backend, shots = 1024)
counts = job.result().get_counts()
plot_histogram(counts)
```

However, this error was shown:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-b48ae13f56aa> in <module>
     11 circuit.measure(q[1],c[1])
     12 
---> 13 job = execute(circuit, backend, shots = 1024)
     14 counts = job.result().get_couns()
     15 plot_histogram(counts)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/qiskit/execute.py in execute(experiments, backend, basis_gates, coupling_map, backend_properties, initial_layout, seed_transpiler, optimization_level, pass_manager, qobj_id, qobj_header, shots, memory, max_credits, seed_simulator, default_qubit_los, default_meas_los, schedule_los, meas_level, meas_return, memory_slots, memory_slot_size, rep_time, rep_delay, parameter_binds, schedule_circuit, inst_map, meas_map, scheduling_method, init_qubits, **run_config)
    258                                 seed_transpiler=seed_transpiler,
    259                                 optimization_level=optimization_level,
--> 260                                 backend=backend)
    261 
    262     if schedule_circuit:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/qiskit/compiler/transpile.py in transpile(circuits, backend, basis_gates, coupling_map, backend_properties, initial_layout, layout_method, routing_method, translation_method, seed_transpiler, optimization_level, pass_manager, callback, output_name)
    211                                            callback, output_name)
    212 
--> 213     _check_circuits_coupling_map(circuits, transpile_args, backend)
    214 
    215     # Transpile circuits in parallel

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/qiskit/compiler/transpile.py in _check_circuits_coupling_map(circuits, transpile_args, backend)
    244 
    245         # If coupling_map is None, the limit might be in the backend (like in 1Q devices)
--> 246         elif backend is not None and not backend.configuration().simulator:
    247             max_qubits = backend.configuration().n_qubits
    248 

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'configuration'
```

I think that the problem is hidden in getting backends or `execute` command.

*Note: I run my code in Quantum Lab on IBM Q website interface.*

**Could any please help me how to change my code to run it on real IBM Q processor?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like `backend = provider.backends(name='ibmq_ourense')` returns a list of backends whose name is `ibmq_oursense` (a list whose length is obviously 1). Try `backend = provider.backends(name='ibmq_ourense')[0]`.

Comment: You can also do `provider.get_backend('ibmq_ourense')`, which will return a single backend instead of a list.

Comment: @jyu00: Thanks, it also works.

Comment: Thanks, it works.

Comment: I was unable to run my circuit on iBMQ .. BUT WITH YOUR HELP IT WORKED.. THANKS.